# integer to float conversion after read

Tags: python, c

I've integers numbers (with sign), each read from 4 bytes, but they should
be read as a floating numbers in first place... So values are totally wrong.

How I can convert them if I cannot read original file? I just have those wrong integers.

### Details

I see my question is not clear. Firstly, please consider the difference between binary format of integers and floating point numbers.

There was a (binary) file where every 4 bytes where numbers. 
But first developer thought they were stored as integers with sign, and he read those bytes like that. Then he save it in a text file:

```
1059629445
1061956142
1062430937
1062311316
1062487958
```

And I got that text file but not original binary file. I know they should be read as float numbers (4 bytes long too). And the result should look like this:

```
0.658837
0.797519
0.825819
0.818689
0.829217
```

I know the result now, because I got the binary file in the meantime, but knowing the answer to this question would be very useful.

How to convert (that's maybe wrong word - rather reinterpret) those numbers?

Comment: whatever, python is probably more handy for me

Comment: I'm bit lost in Python. It should be struct.pack() and then unpack() probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in an early comment (now deleted), this sort of processing can be and often is accomplished using the[`struct`module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct). So, given a text file with the integers in it as shown in your question, here's one way to do the conversion/reinterpretion:

```
import struct

# convert integer on each line of text file into a list of Python int objects
with open('ints.txt') as ints_file:
    ints = [int(line) for line in ints_file]

# convert list of ints into list of 4-byte binary strings
binaries = [struct.pack('i', i) for i in ints]

# convert list of 4-byte binary strings into list of Python floating point values
floats = [struct.unpack('f', b)[0] for b in binaries]  # unpack() returns a tuple

print 'input:'
for value in ints:
    print '  {:d}'.format(value)
print
print 'results:'
for value in floats:
    print '  {:.5f}'.format(value)
```

Output:

```
input:
  1059629445
  1061956142
  1062430937
  1062311316
  1062487958

results:
  0.65884
  0.79752
  0.82582
  0.81869
  0.82922
```

This can be optimized and shortened, which in this case might actually make it easier to see the 3 conversion steps applied, one after the other:`int()`, `struct.pack()`, and`struct.unpack()`.

```
with open('ints.txt') as ints_file:
    print 'results:'
    for line in ints_file:
        print '  %.5f' % struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('i', int(line)))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`:

```
float res;
int value;
... 
memcpy(&res, &value, sizeof(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below logic will help you

```
int a;
void *v;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &a);
v = &a;
fprintf(fp, "%f", *((float*)v));
```

As size of `float` and `int` are 4 bytes in most of the system.

Comment: Please see new Details in my question

Comment: This can fail if the alignment requirements for `float` are different than those for `int`; also, it violates the strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear.I think may be this will help you...

```
int i=5;
printf("in float the value is=%f",(float)i);
```

the output will be in float.

Comment: Please see new Details in my question

Answer (score 0):

If you perform type conversion from int to float it will give you the desired result.

```
int myIntNum = 100;
float myFloatNum = (float)myIntNum;
```